# Picture of the week theme for contest starting July 30th: Science

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

The theme for the contest running the week of July 30th will be "[Science](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/1917)".  Submit your best work which fits within the theme and all the usual rules. The winning photo will be displayed beginning August 6 or 7.

Have fun!